# Saving user input values into an array

Tags: arrays, r, while-loop

Essentially I want to save all of the user inputs into an array and add them when the user enters a 0. I don't know how to do that. In my script, the x value will inevitably be changed every time.

Here's my script so far:

```
print("This program will sum a series of numbers.")
x <- 1:100    
num <- c(x)
while (num[x] != 0) {
    print("Enter the next number (enter 0 when finished)")
    num[x] <- as.numeric(readLines(con=stdin(),1))
}
sum <- sum(num)
print(paste("The sum of your numbers is", sum))
```

I get this error:

> In while (num[x] != 0) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
print("This program will sum a series of numbers.")
next_entry <- 1
entries <- vector()
while (next_entry != 0) {
print("Enter the next number (enter 0 when finished)")
next_entry <- as.numeric(readLines(con=stdin(),1))
entries <- c(entries, next_entry)
}
sum <- sum(entries)
print(paste("The sum of your numbers is", sum))
```

The problem with your script is that "num" is already defined, since you set it to 1:100 on the 3rd line.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much.